# Spring oauth2 sso example doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to repeat actions described in the [official tutorial(Spring Boot and OAuth2)](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)

I stuck on the section [Hosting an Authorization Server](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver)

I tried to download all [sources from github](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2.git) but result the same

I am trying to start sub project `social-auth-server`:

I found 2 starters there:

`src\main\java\com\example\SocialApplication.java` - oauth2 server
`src\test\java\com\example\ClientApplication.java` - oauth2 client

quote from the tutorial:

> Note that the server.context-path is set explicitly, so if you run the
>   app to test it remember the home page is http://localhost:9999/client.
>   Clicking on that link should take you to the auth server and once you
>   you have authenticated with the social provider of your choice you
>   will be redirected back to the client app

1.I've started both applications
2. In browser I type `localhost:9999/client`
3. As a result of previous step - browser redirects me to the `localhost:8080`
4. I click `Login via Facebook`
5. As a result of previous step - browser redirects me to the Facebook to input credentials.
6. I typed correct credentials
7. As a result of previous step - browser redirects me to the `localhost:8080`. Even without my name on this page.

I expected that the browser would redirect me to the `localhost:9999` and show me message `Hello Nikolay!`

Can you please help me with this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You are using application.yml as defined in the tutorial . That Facebook app is registered with localhost:8080 url. It is specified in that tutorial itself.

> The configuration refers to a client app registered with Facebook in
>   their developers site, in which you have to supply a registered
>   redirect (home page) for the app. This one is registered to
>   "localhost:8080" so it only works in an app running on that address.

Try to create your own facebook app with redirect URL as `localhost:9999`  in configuration. Add your app's configuration in application.yml

OAuth Auth server will always try to redirect tokens to configured redirect url

Comment: where can I reconfigure facebook?

Comment: The App defined in tutorial may be created by spring. Try to login into https://developers.facebook.com/ .there you can create app

Comment: ,Do you want to say that application from tutorial doesn't work?

Comment: Doesn't work as you expected. It will redirect to localhost:8080

Comment: So I can change client app port to 8080 and auth server  to anoter(for example 8081) and everything should work. Is is correct?

Comment: it doesn't work anyway. because my oauth client(8080) redirects to the  my oauth server(9999) which redirects to the facebook and facebook responds that redirectUri mismatch